# While creating AppiumDriver object why its showing two abstract method?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, appium

```
 driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("localhost:4723/wd/hub"),cap) {

        @Override
        public MobileElement scrollToExact(String arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public MobileElement scrollTo(String arg0) {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

After creating driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("localhost:4723/wd/hub"),cap) its automatically added two abstract method.

But in tutorial everywhere, these methods are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

AppumDriver is abstract and extended by AndroidDriver and IOSDriver.These scroll methods are implemented differently for Android and iOS. So you are seeing these methods as and when you create AppumDriver instance.

Comment: but every where the tutorials are there I didn't see these two methods

Comment: Which version of Appium java-client you are using?

Comment: I am using Appium-1.2.4.1

Comment: Can you please try with latest java-client? These methods are reimplemented in latest version (as per change log - https://github.com/appium/java-client#changelog)

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know.